How can i restrict api access in a react frontend and c# backend app?
I have an app that authenticates a user using MSAL and that is in the client side , react.
But on the backend , c# i make api calls and I want to add some Authorization to only allow users who have successfully logged into the app.
How can i do this, is there an example  ?

if you are using Azure MSAL., you will be provided with token from azure AD. you can send AuthToken in request headers which can be decoded and validated in API services in backend.
Here is an example of axios get and post methods which uses Auth Token..


import axios from 'axios';

// in getToken method., write logic to get Auth token using `useMsal` method.
const token = getToken();

axios.get(`/api/your_url`, {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
  },
})
.then((response) => console.log(response))
.catch((response) => console.log(error));



You can get token with help of useMsal methods available in msal-react plugin.

and what do i do on the backend , I really need a full working example. How do i use the token to authorize ?
